# jQuery beforeSend doesn't see element

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have this html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>UC</title>
        <!-- css -->

        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- scripts -->
        <script src="<?php echo URL; ?>public/js/application.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="form">form</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this JS:

```
var URL = "https://192.168.2.112/pm-nc/ajax"
$(document).ready(preparePage());

function preparePage(){
    //check if user is logged in
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            request: "loginCheck"   
        },
        url: URL,
        dataType: "html",
        beforeSend: function(){
            alert($("#form").length);
        },
        success: function(data){
            $("#form").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

and I am trying insert some loading gif into element with id form, but it looks like when script starts element with id form doesn't exist yet. Alert shows 0. Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need id selector `$('#form')`. Note # sign. `$('form')` means "find all form elements".

Comment: thanks from note, i edit code, but still doesn't work.